# Asterisk after new in 2d array

Tags: c++

What is the use of a * after new int in this code? Why can't we write 2d array without * after new int?

```
int *p1=new int[3];
int *p2=new int[3];

int **pData= new int*[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of the * after new int is, as you said, for the 2d array.

Without the *, it is simply a 1d array.

There is a similar question which could be useful:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39397322/declaring-a-2d-array-using-double-pointer)

Comment: `int*` is a type, and `new int*[2]` allocates memory for an array of 2 of those. That's all. It is not a 2-dimensional array. It's the subsequent code that uses it to create a 2-d array.

Answer (score 0):

`new int*[2]` says to allocate storage for an array of 2 `int*`. There's nothing special here: `int*` is the name of the type being created. The code uses that array of `int*` to create a 2-dimensional array, but that's in the rest of the code; `new int*[2]` on its own is simply an array of pointers.

But, yes, you can create a 2-dimensional array directly, without that intervening layer of pointers:

```
int (*p)[3] = new int[2][3];
```

This defines `p` to be a pointer to an array of 3 `int`. And, because the `new` expression gives the dimension for that array, you've got a 2-dimensional array. It acts just the way you'd hope for:

```
p[1][2] = 7;
std::cout << p[1][2] << '\n';
```

Answer (score -1):

`*` is a pointer, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6043886/5305519) out for an explanation of using pointers in C++